# convert list of list to dictionary with some key pattern

Tags: python

I am looking to convert a list of lists which contains some details in the below format into a dictionary.

```
[['1234567890', 'abcdef', 'xyzd'],
 ['0987654321', 'pqrstuvw', 'oiu'],
 ['6767547879', 'djkaddsd', 'dsad']]
```

I want it to be in the below format.

```
{'target0': ['1234567890', 'abcdef', 'xyzd'],
 'target1': ['0987654321', 'pqrstuvw', 'oiu'],
 'target2': ['6767547879', 'djkaddsd', 'dsad']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer `enumerate` in a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {f'target{k}': v for k, v in enumerate(lst)}
{'target0': ['1234567890', 'abcdef', 'xyzd'], 
 'target1': ['0987654321', 'pqrstuvw', 'oiu'], 
 'target2': ['6767547879', 'djkaddsd', 'dsad']}
>>>
```

Also I used `f`-strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension) for a nice one liner :)

```
output = {'target'+str(x):values[x] for x in range(len(values))}
```

This outputs:

```
{'target0': ['1234567890', 'abcdef', 'xyzd'],
 'target1': ['0987654321', 'pqrstuvw', 'oiu'],
 'target2': ['6767547879', 'djkaddsd', 'dsad']}
```

Comment: For iterating over indices *and* values, `enumerate()` is much cleaner. See [U12-Forward's answer](/a/70179093/4518341).